# Exception on SmtpClient.sendAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I'm trying to send emails using `SmtpClient.SendAsync` in my app, but I'm getting an exception. Below is my code related to sending emails:

```
//preparing message data
....
....

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(_smtpServer);
client.Timeout = TIMEOUT;
//client.Send(message);  //this works well.
object userState = message;
client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
client.SendAsync(message, userState);
```

Callback:

```
    private static void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get the Original MailMessage object
        MailMessage mail = (MailMessage)e.UserState;

        //write out the subject
        string subject = mail.Subject;

        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Send canceled for mail with subject [{0}].", subject);
        }
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error {1} occurred when sending mail [{0}] ", subject, e.Error.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message [{0}] sent.", subject);
        }
    }
```

The exception is:

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async=\"true\" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an \"async void\" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it."}  System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}`.

I've seen online saying that I need <%@Page Async="true"%> in my .aspx file. But My app is hybrid angular mobile app. Which means I got .aspx for desktop version, .html for mobile versions. So I'm not really sure where should I put it?

Comment: Why do you want to use `SendAsync`? What advantage do you think it's going to give you over `Send`?

Comment: @mason Because in my case, I need to send emails to a list of email addresses, which potentially can be 10+ or so, it takes quite some time with the sync send when testing.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be doing this in the web server anyways. That's more appropriate for a background task.

Comment: @mason To me, sending emails to a long list should be background task. I'm not getting what you said. It also doesn't give an answer to my question... Could you leave an answer below if you have one? Thanks.

Comment: Long running operations that take more than a couple of seconds do not belong in your web application. That ties up threads and can result in slow performance for all users. Instead, you should have this code execute in the background. That might be as simple as enqueuing a [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) job from your web server and then having a console app execute the Hangfire job. Or you might implement a queue system such as [RabbitMQ](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit) and have a separate service application handle processing items off the queue.

Comment: "That ties up threads and can result in slow performance for all users", I think this is the result of using `send`, and that's why I'm trying to use `sendAsync`, which will not ties up threads.

Comment: Yes, yes it will. How do you think the code is going to run if it's not using a thread? Async is not a magic bullet. You *might* be able to make this operation go faster for the one request using parallelism, but that will just use even more threads up. This type of work belongs in a background process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141383/discussion-between-yabin-song-and-mason).